# Are MIME headers mandatory for a SOAP request?

Tags: java, wsdl, soap-client

While building a `SOAP` request to be sent to a webservice, do I need to include `MIME` Headers or are they optional?

And do I need to specify the `MIME` type in the `WSDL`?

Answer (score 1):

If you build your SOAP request from scratch by your own you have to set the MIME-Type.

The default MIME-Type for a SOAP request is

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;
```

Also add the charset

```
charset=utf-8
```

There is no need to specify the `MIME` type in the `WSDL`. The content of a `SOAP` request is by default `application/soap+xml`.